# Problems with overriding compareTo() in interface Comparable

Tags: java, oop, if-statement, comparator, comparable

I'm working on a programm that has to override the CompareTo() in Comparable to make Collections.sort() work. For I am working with an ArrayList made up of Assistants, that I have to sort depending on the name.

I've looked around the forum and found that and tried changing

```
public class Assistant{
```

to

```
public class Assistant implements Comparable<Assistant>{
```

which in return allows me to use the Collections.sort() in another class and doesn't warn me about any errors, however, two new errors appear.

To start with, in this same line

```
public class Assistant implements Comparable<Assistant>{
```

it tells me that "it is not abstract and does not override compareTo(Assistant) in Comparable." And when I go to the compareTo() I've created:

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o2){
        Assistant m2 = (Assistant) o2;

        if(this.name.compareTo(m2.name) == 0){
            return 0;
        }else if(this.name.compareTo(m2.name)<0){
            return -1;
        }else{
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

(The Assistant's constructor only has name in it).

However, in this place I have an error in @Override :
"method does not override or implement a method from a supertype".

And in the next line

```
    public int compareTo(Object o2){
```

I get another error (which is related to the last) telling me:
"Name clash: compareTo(Object) in Assistant and compareTo(Assistant) in Assistant have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other."

I sort of understand the problem, I am not overriding the original compareTo().

I'm a newbie at java, therefore if anyone finds the problem I would be grateful if you could also explain what I am doing wrong (or missing).

Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you have parametrized `Comparable` (type parameter is `Assistant`). This should do it (I have simplified it a bit):

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Assistant o){
    return this.name.compareTo(o.name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're implementing Comparable, your compareTo() method requires a parameter of type Assistent.

So using this should work:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Assistent m2) {

    if(this.name.compareTo(m2.name) == 0){
        return 0;
    }else if(this.name.compareTo(m2.name)<0){
        return -1;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This because to have Comparable of type `Assistant`

Change

```
public int compareTo(Object o2)
```

To,

```
public int compareTo(Assistant o2)
```

Answer (score 1):

To the already correctly stated examples of how the implementation would compile, I'll add some rules for you to remember with regards to overriding methods:

1. To override a method you need to use the same method name,
2. a covariant (backwards compatible) return type,
3. same or broader access type, but not narrower.
4. However the parameter list must differ.

Number 4 explains why you need to change the parameter type from Object to Assistant in order for it to successfully override the compareTo() method.